# How canonical are integral lifts of Hasse invariants and other mod-$p$ modular forms?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Recall that the [mod $p$ Hasse invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Witt_matrix) $A$ of an elliptic curve is an $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$-modular form of weight $p-1$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Writing $\overline{\mathcal{M}_{ell}}$ for the compactified moduli stack of elliptic curves, I think this means that $A$ is a section of the bundle $\omega^{p-1} / p$. It is "essentially the only" mod-$p$ modular form whose Fourier expansion is $A(q) = 1 \in \mathbb{F}_p[\![q]\!]$.

When $p \geq 5$, $A$ is [liftable to an integral modular form](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228497/). For example, the (normalized) weight-4 Eisenstein series is $E_4 = 1 + 240\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n^3q^n}{1-q^n} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ lifts the mod-5 Hasse invariant, and $E_6 = 1 + 504\sum(\dots) \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ lifts the mod-7 Hasse invariant. These lifts are "canonical" just because there aren't very many integral modular forms of those degrees.

What about the higher primes? Is there a "canonical" lift of the mod-$p$ Hasse invariant? For instance, in $12$, the space of integral modular forms is $2$-dimensional, spanned by $c_4^3$ and $\Delta = q + O(q)$, and so naively "the" integral lift of the mod-$13$ Hasse invariant suffers, at least, an ambiguity of multiples of $13\Delta$.

I would also like to hear about the case of the prime $p=3$. Then the mod-$3$ Hasse invariant $A$ is not liftable (at level $1$ — it is liftable as as $\Gamma_1(N)$-modular form for $N\geq 2$ coprime to $3$). But maybe there are some mod-$3$ modular forms which are liftable, like $AE_4$ or $AE_6$, and maybe they are liftable "canonically"?

Comment: No one would accuse me of being a number theorist. Please let me know about any errors of theory or notation.

Comment: For any $p \ge 5$ you have the level 1 Eisenstein series $E_{p-1}$, and that's very commonly regarded as the "standard" lifting of the Hasse invariant.

Comment: You should only  expect to have "canonical" lifts of $A$ to (possibly non-reduced) rings $R$ with $pR = 0$.  Note that $E_4$ is a lift of $A^2 \pmod 3$ when $p = 3$ and $A^4 \pmod 4$ when $p = 2$. Of course @DavidLoeffler is completely correct that $E_{p-1}$ is taken as a standard choice but it might be more useful for you to specify what properties you would like your lift to satisfy or what you would want to do with it.